# Dynamic Linq with a database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, search, dynamic

I am trying to understand dynamic linq as used by Scott Guthrie in this example [Dynamic Query](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx)

Scott attached a file as an example in the CsharpSamples file where he uses a dynamic query to look in multiple columns for a search. I am trying to understand how a dynamic query works so I may adapt his code to work in my program.

This code snippet below is giving me the most trouble

```
var query = db.Customers.Where("City == @0 and Orders.Count >= @1", "London", 10).
            OrderBy("CompanyName").
            Select("New(CompanyName as Name, Phone)");
```

I am not understanding why on the first line he hard codes the value "London and "10"?

I want to use dynamic Query for a search function where the table is called `iamp_mapping` and the columns I would like to search are called `PA, Major Program, Investment_Area, Director` and `VP`.

I want to the user to be able to use a single search box to search every column for the existence of a value. Also here is the search function I would like to use to search for the value. I was able to get it working with a single column search but not with every column.

```
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
{
}
```

I hope that this makes sense, please feel free to ask any questions that would help diagnose my problem. I will be checking back often.

Comment: It is hardcoded because the search values are just for an example. You can easily change them or even use a variable there.

Comment: Ok that makes sense but then say I replace City with PA and Orders with Major_Program. How would I use it to search when I don't care if PA or Major_Program == anything I just want it to search every field?

Comment: Add all fields and just use @0 everywhere as value to search for?

Comment: I don't think I am understanding Styxxy here is what I just tried var query = db.iamp_mapping.OrderBy("searchString").Select("new(searchString as PA, MAJOR_PROGRAM)");

Comment: I don't understand how to use the @0 and the where I think? Thanks for your help if answer in the answer section I can upvote you thanks for responding so quick!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand from your comment, you would like something like this:

```
var query = db.iamp_mapping.Where("PA == %0 and Major_Program == %0 and Investment_Area == %0 and Director == @0 and VP == @0", "ValueToSearchFor").
            OrderBy("...").
            Select("...");
```

Note: I didn't test it exactly, but from my intuition, I would say this works. Of course you still have to add the OrderBy and Select correctly.

The `@0` is just the first value parameter you give the `Where` method.

Comment: I keep getting a parse error if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
            {

                var query = db.iamp_mapping.Where("PA == %0 and MAJOR_PROGRAM == %0").
                    OrderBy("PA").
                    Select("New(PA as PA,MAJOR_PROGRAM)");               
            }

Comment: What kind of parse error do you have? You need to provide a little bit more information.

Comment: sure sorry about that here is a screen grab of the parse error let me know if you need anything else and thanks again for your help! [http://i.imgur.com/j3K9Y.jpg]